# Testing iOS-app on device while offline

Tags: ios, testing, device, offline

I have a paid Apple developer account. I'm using Xcode 8.0 with iOS 10.0.1 on an iPhone 6 plus.

Starting the app on the device works, I verified the developer app certificate on the iPhone.

So I want to test my app while device is offline on starting the app. In Xcode I got the message:

"Verify the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on iPhone Plus and navigate to General -> Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it."

I have to go online to verify. Then I go offline again and same thing happens.

My question: How to test an app on device while offline on starting the app?

Comment: It has been mentioned already that you have to trust your certificate. Install your app, trust it, then open the app in offline.

Comment: As I told, I installed my app, trusted it, app started. Close the app, put the device offline, want to start the app again -> message...

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204460

Comment: Yes I know this. I've done this! My iPhone is trusting me as a developer as long as the device is online when starting the app. 
It seems, that on starting the app, there is an attempt to connect to apple and if the connection can't be established, the certificate will be refused...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Network Link Conditioner "100% Loss", but it does not work or work, but the app does not start because of the cert problem.

**Easiest solution**

- switch off WiFi
- Use mobile network
- Start the app (have to download data)
- Go to Settings -> Mobile Network -> Switch off the app's data usage

If you only use mobile network the app starts in offline mode.

**Tricky but working solution without SIM card (Xcode 10.1, iOS 12.1.2, iPhone 5S)**

- start the app in Xcode
- open Control Center on the phone
- if the Control Center closes, imminently open it back and touch the Airplane mode

The app starts in offline mode.

**Another solution without debug (sometimes work)**

- go to Airplane mode
- start the app from the phone